# Display response JSON data from laravel validate

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

i have response json like this :

```
{
"code": ["The code field is required."],
"nama":["The nama field is required."],
"deskripsi":["The deskripsi field is required."]
}
```

how can i display just " name : value "

Answer (score 0):

your response is an object from the much i can gather. If so:

```
 <p> name : {response.name}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let response = {
"code": ["The code field is required."],
"nama":["The nama field is required..."],
"deskripsi":["The deskripsi field is required."]
}
console.log(response.nama[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as shown below if the element only exist in 0th position, Or if you are checking for dynamic please post the sample snippet response

for the current question this will work

```
import React from "react";

const response = {
  "code": ["The code field is required."],
  "nama":["The nama field is required."],
  "deskripsi":["The deskripsi field is required."]
  }
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
    Name : {response.nama[0]}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```